# React Native input based on how much someone swipes an object

Tags: react-native, user-input, swipe, swiper.js, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm building an app in React Native (using Expo), and I need to build a UI where the user swipes an object, and how far they swipe corresponds to a different input (I'm not talking about a slider, I want to slide an image up and based on how far the user swipes it up it will render a different input). On release of the object, that input will be recorded and the next item will be loaded.

Do you guys have any idea how to implement such a UI? I was looking into the react-native-gesture-handler library, and was thinking of using the PanGestureHandler (linked below) to implement this, but I was wondering if there was a better way. This seems like it would be a little complicated to implement and was wondering if there was any third party library that already did something like this, or if there was a better way to do this.

Thanks for all the help.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/pan-gh/

Comment: Here's a package: https://github.com/miblanchard/react-native-slider